# GPU code generation with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cuda, opencl, code-generation

Is there a MATLAB code generator that creates openCL or CUDA GPU code from MATLAB?

I know of the C++ code generator, and of the MATLAB Parallel Computing toolbox that can run on the GPU, but I couldn't find any documentation as to code generation.

Can anyone shed light on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not now, but GPU code generation is an upcoming feature.